# how to handle close connection Exception in websockets and asyncio (Python)?

Tags: python, exception, python-asyncio

I am using websockets and asyncio in Python 3.6.3 on windows cygwin.

This is my code:

```
class DataReader:
    def __init__(self, address):
        self.address = address

    async def create_socket(self):
        self.socket = await websockets.connect(self.address)

    async def send(self, message):
        await self.socket.send(message)
    async def receive(self):
        return await self.socket.recv()

    def on_message(self):
        return await self.socket.recv()

    def start(self):
        asyncio.async(self.start_async())

    async def start_async(self):
        try:
            self.socket = await websockets.connect(self.address)
            while True:
                message = await self.socket.recv()
                self.on_message(message)
            except:
                print("Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[0])
                self.start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    url = "wss://a url"
    reader = DataReader(url)
    reader.start()
    asyncio.get_event_loop.run_forever()
```

It was slightly simplified for reading.

It run and outputted correctly  for a while, but later nothing was printed. I pressed ctrl+C, and got this on exiting:

```
Exception ignored in: 
    <generator object WebSocketCommonProtocol.close_connection at 0x6fffe9349e8>
RuntimeError: generator ignored GeneratorExit
```

Did it means the try catch not working? Or did I do it the wrong way?

Comment: I have transcribed the code from the image you attached. In the future [please do not upload images of code](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551), instead copy-and-paste the code into the question body in a code block.

Answer (score 0):

```
except:
```

[You should never do such thing](https://docs.python.org/3.0/howto/doanddont.html#except) since it catches also service (non-error) exceptions such as `GeneratorExit`.

Change it with:

```
except Exception:
```